# JPA exception while saving an Entity in Oracle 10g

Tags: java, database, oracle, jpa, playframework

I am using Play framework 1.2.4 for my application but the exception seems is related to JPA.

I have a `Composite Key` in my Oracle 10g database, hence I used `@IdClass` approach for JPA operations.

Below is the `Primary Key` class:

```
public class ItemDetailsPK implements Serializable {    
public String itemId;
public String itemName;
}
```

Below is the `Entity` class:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(ItemDetailsPK.class)
@Table(name="ITEM_DETAILS")
public class ItemDetails extends GenericModel { 
@Id
@Column(name="ITEM_ID")
public String itemId;
@Id
@Column(name="ITEM_NAME")
public String itemName;
```

Below is the method I used for saving an item:

```
public static void addItem(ItemDetails itemDetails){
        // Saving the Item
        itemDetails.save(); // Throwing Exception
    }
}
```

The Exception message is:

`Composite Id Property missing:models.ItemDetails.ItemId (Defined in IdClass ItemDetailsPK)`

**Note: **

1 thing I found while debugging the code: When I hover the mouse over the `itemDetails` argument of `addItem` method, I can see this exception in the attached with the object: **com.sun.jndi.invocationexception occured invoking the method**

**Update**

If I surround the entire `addItem` method in a `try/catch` block then the save operation is working fine but still the exception message is getting displayed in the console for `e.printStackTrace();` in a catch block.

Kindly let me know how to resolve this exception.

Comment: I just wonder why it's "ItemDetails.ItemId"(Uppercase I in ItemId) in the exception message?

Comment: Yes, it was my first observation when the exception occurred. I search my entire workspace with the term `ItemId` with uppercase `I` but did not got anything. Moreover, if I surround the entire method with a `try/catch` block then the save is also working but still the exception is getting displayed in the console. Please check the above updated post and let me know if you have any idea on how to fix this.